# File Upload control in update Panel Always returns false

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `detailsView` inside the update panel., and in the detailsView I have a `FileUpload` Control and a button `btn_Upload`. In the click event I have written code :

```
if(fileUploadControl.HasFile)
{
    var fileName = fileUploadControl.FileName;
}
```

Always returns `false`, can some one tell me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FileUpload inside UpdatePanel will cause a submit , however it will not work for security reasons - no browser will allow javascript to access random files in our filesystem. I suggest you use this http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx instead to do what you have in mind.

Another person who has worked around this issue blogs about it [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/mmintoff/archive/2009/04/01/fileupload-within-updatepanel.aspx).

Comment: If it's causing a submit then why won't it work? And if it's submitting by input type="file" then why is javascript accessing random files on your filesystem?

Comment: In the background ASP.NET javascript stops the submit from completing, and then does an XMLHTTP post instead. It is this javascript that takes all the values of the fields that are within the update panel and sends them to the server via an XHR request. So this javascript when it encounters the [input type=file] It skips the field as it cannot get the value out of it (because of browser security) browser does not allow ASP.NET javascript to access the file user selected in the [input type=file].

Answer (score 1):

Its just a problem with the FileUpload control inside an update panel. To get it to work you will need to do a full postback. Or use an alternative